# Hexadecimal string to decimal conversion

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pyspark columns consisting of following hexadecimal values:

```
Value            | 245FC;324EE;
Value_Split      | [245FC,324EE]
```

I would like to convert them to the following decimal numbers:

```
Value            | 148988;206062;
Value_Split      | [148988,206062]
```

I am happy, even one column conversion happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conv` function to change hexadecimal to the decimal.

**Spark >= 3.1.0**

```
df.withColumn('Value_Split', f.transform('Value_Split', lambda v: f.conv(v, 16, 10))) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----------------+
|Value_Split     |
+----------------+
|[148988, 206062]|
+----------------+
```

**Spark >= 2.4.0**

```
df.withColumn('Value_Split', f.expr('transform(Value_Split, v -> conv(v, 16, 10))')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----------------+
|Value_Split     |
+----------------+
|[148988, 206062]|
+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I use spark version 3.0.3 and transform function is only available from 3.1.0. Please let me know, how to proceed further.